# Area Name is null in OnActionExecuting for default route

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to get current area name inside OnActionExeuting. I'm getting it as below:

```
_areaName =  ctx.RouteData.DataTokens["area"].ToString();
```

This works for all routes except for the default route ( my landing page - logon). The default route is defined as below in global.asax

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new {area = "Home",
            controller = "UserLogon",
            action = "Login",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional
        }
    );
}
```

and the area registration is as below:

```
public override string AreaName
{
    get
    {
        return "Home";
    }
}
 public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
 {
    context.MapRoute(
        "Home_default",
        "Home/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new {controller = "UserLogon", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

    );

 }
```

What am I missing?